# Youtube wont stop on close click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

So I have a popup with a youtube video in it. when the close is clicked the video needs to stop, but continues to play.

Jquery:

```
$(".single-property").on('click',".popup-bg",function(){
    $(".popup-bg").hide();
    $(".video-popup").hide();
    $('#youtubeplayer').each(function(){
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*')
    });
});
```

php:

```
/* Video popup */    
echo    '<div class="video-popup">
    <div class="map-title">';
        if($Property['address']['unit_number']!=NULL){
            echo $Property['address']['unit_number']."/";
        }
echo        $Property['address']['street_number'].' '.$Property['address']['street_name'].'</div>
    <div class="iframe-wrapper">
        <iframe id="youtubeplayer" src="//youtube.com/embed/'.$url.'" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>';
```

also tried this:

```
$('#youtubeplayer')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');  
})
```

As this is code that has worked in the past for me with multiple youtube videos.

Comment: Well you are not stopping video you are just hiding it

Comment: $('#youtubeplayer').each(function(){
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*')
    });

Comment: Try deleting popup and appending again or something.

Comment: not really what I want to do as they may want to open video and continue watching it rather than playing from beginning.

Comment: `$('#youtubeplayer').each(....` ? Each of a unique `#ID`? Do your `stopVideo` *then* do this:`  `$(".popup-bg").hide();`
    `$(".video-popup").hide();`

Comment: I agree with @Stupid Kid. You can set url parameters to auto-play the video when the modal opens and then remove the modal from the DOM when closed. It's very simple and there's no need to use the YouTube API or try to use the postMessage method. I do it this way all the time.

Comment: Did what @Stupid Kid said: var youtubeurl =  $("#youtubeplayer").attr('src'); 
 $("#youtubeplayer").attr('src',''); 
 $("#youtubeplayer").attr('src',youtubeurl);

Comment: not ideal but moving stopVideo above never worked. thanks guys